# Can I give kittens kitten replacement milk even if they are drinking milk from their mum?

Tags: cats, health

My cat gave birth to 3 kittens 3 weeks ago. They are doing well. But one of them is a female and is smaller than the other one. Can I give her some kitten replacement milk (kitten formula) even if she continues to drink her mum's milk?

Edit: She is drinking less than the others it seems.

Comment: Have you observed that she isn't getting enough to eat? Some cats are just smaller than others. What behaviors have you noticed during nursing periods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that mum cat is ok with you handling the kittens, I don't see any issues with giving supplemental replacement kitten milk.  Be aware that there are special products you should use.

See related:

- [Kitten Food in an Emergency](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1715/13)
- [Can you bottle feed a kitten?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/3250/13)
- [Mother cat won't care for her newborn kitten](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/20664/13)
- [taking care of newborn cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/21498/13)

Note: There are potentially some duplicate questions here, I did not attempt to identify or address the duplicate status of these questions when listing the related